# Prevent compiler from optimizing away unused struct type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a bunch of structs that are only used by [natvis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects) during debugging. It turns out natvis could not use them until I actually declared variables of such types. Looks like the compiler was discarding them. Natvis was giving the following error: `Error: identifier "MyType" is undefined`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler not to discard unused structs declaration without declaring unused variables?

I'm thinking with GCC I could use `__attribute__((used))`, though I'm not sure that applies to struct declaration, what can I use in my case for MSVC?

Comment: if you don't create instances of a type, how can you use the type?

Comment: As mentioned above it was only used by the debugger visualizers.

Comment: Presumably, you want to use these in a debugging build, so you can just declare some redundant variables bracketed by `#ifndef _DEBUG` ... `#endif`

Comment: or maybe reduce the optimisation level

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I was trying to reproduce the problem as I thought it might have been fixed by having the natvis file part of the Visual Studio project but somehow it would not reproduce. Maybe it needed a clean recompile but I can't be bothered for now. Hopefully it will work without the variable declarations and the natvis in the project/solution.

Comment: Ok after a clean and rebuild I can reproduce the issue even with the natvis in the solution so I'm going to have to live with declaring variables of said types within `#ifdef _DEBUG` for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [[maybe_unused]] attribute or #pragma optimize( "", off ).

Comment: Thought pragma optimize was for functions rather than type declarations.

Comment: `[[maybe_unused]]` ain't working which is inline with the documentation cause it says it is only there to suppress warnings.

Comment: `#pragma optimize` also not working.